# ng-repeat not working in ssr render email - angular-meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email, meteor, angular-meteor

I am using SSR.Render module with angular-meteor to send emails.

But ng-repeat isn't working on an array.

**Here is the HTML code:**

```
<div ng-repeat="result in articles">
{{result}}
</div>
```

Here is the Email SSR.Render code:

```
SSR.compileTemplate( 'emailTemplate', Assets.getText( 'emails/emailTemplate.html' ) );

            var emailData = {
              articles: [ 'John', 'Mark', 'Mick' ]
            };

            Email.send({
              to: 'someuser@email.com',
              from: "Some website",
              subject: "Hey, you got an email",
              html: SSR.render( 'emailTemplate', emailData )
            });
```

The above code doesn't loop the HTML. Can anyone guide me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Where do you assign data to $scope.articles?

Comment: This is the server side code. I am pushing email from server and preparing related data on server and passing it to html using SSR Render

Comment: I will try it out (so, I'm not sure), but I think SSR was built to render Blaze templates only (not Angular).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because meteor currently only supports angularjs on the client side. ( Not 100% sure )